# Cycling through a sub set of tabs to HIde Auto Filter Arrows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through a sub set of tabs to hide the auto filter arrows on a single table in each tab. The .ShowHideFilter = False works fine if I execute it individually on each tab. I assume I am not naming the .ShowHideFilter correctly. I get the "Subscript out of range" error.

```
Sub HideFilterArrows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

For Each ws In Worksheets
    Select Case LCase(ws.Name)
        Case "mastersheet", "merge", "index", "control", "Timeline", "chartdata"
        Case Else
            'Go to next worksheet
            Worksheets(ws.Name).Activate
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ShowAutoFilter = False
    End Select
Next

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `Worksheets(ws.Name).Activate; ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ShowAutoFilter = False`, just use `ws.ListObjects(1).ShowAutoFilter`. The `Activate` is not necessary. Also, lower the "T" in your "Timeline" sheet name.

Comment: You should also check to make sure there is a table on the worksheet:  `If ws.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then ...`

Comment: You're intending to do this to each sheet that is **not** one of ("mastersheet", "merge", "index", "control", "timeline", "chartdata"), correct?

Comment: Yes, I am want to hide arrows on all sheets except those listed. I get a Compile error "Invalid use of property" on .ShowAutoFilter

Comment: I get the error when I use, ws.ListObjects(1).ShowAutoFilter

Comment: Check my edit in the answer it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, its not pretty but it works.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "mastersheet", "merge", "index", "control", "Timeline", "chartdata"

        Case Else
            Dim x As ListObject 
            For Each x In ws.ListObjects
                x.ShowAutoFilter = False
            Next x
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: Code took a long time looping, but no update occurred. There are tables on the target sheets, because if I run a single step macro of ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ShowAutoFilter = False only, the arrows are hidden on the table.

Comment: Try replacing .UsedRange with .ListObjects(1), i don't have any tables to test it on.

Comment: @user8038235, I used the.ShowAutoFilter and had to replace `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)` with `ws.ListObjects(1)`,  it should work, if it does not please give me feedback.

Comment: With .ListObjects(1) I get the Subscript out of range error again.

Comment: Do you have multiple tables?

Comment: @PeterT's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953521/cycling-through-a-sub-set-of-tabs-to-hide-auto-filter-arrows#comment90858329_51953521) is spot on, you need to check if the Worksheet has any ListObjects

Comment: @user8038235; each `listobject` has its own number so you have to loop through each one. Using `Listobjects(1)` only effects the first `listobject`. The current edit should work.

Comment: There is only one table on each sheet, that I want to hide arrows on.

Comment: @BigBen; using `Listobjects(1)` the For loop was stopping at the first table.

Comment: @user8038235; Thank you, your issue was interesting.

Comment: Thanks much, that did the trick. Do I need to add the the recommended check if sheet has table?

Comment: @user8038235; I tested with mock data and a worksheet without any tables, and had not problems.